# Microdata and divs

Tags: html, microdata

My two divs (`article-tag-summary` and `article-date-summary`) belong under `article-image-summary` div. This is good and cannot change.

Everything belongs under `schema.org/Article`, thus also `<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">`.

Issues:

1. 1 - If I close `<div class="article-image-summary"
   itemprop="image">`, then the two divs fall outside the image and
   this is bad for my CSS styling.
2. 2 - If I do NOT close it, then
   `itemprop="articleSection` and `itemprop="datePublished` are NOT
   recognised in schema.org because they relate to `ImageObject` and
   NOT `schema.org/Article` which is also bad.

This is a purely HTML problem... what I need is to have the `date-summary` and `tag-summary` fall under `image-summary` (so NOT closing div before them), and that these two divs have itemprops that relate to `schema.org/Article` and NOT to `ImageObject`.

The example below shows the two closing divs before date and tag, meaning the schema.org validation works. But in this case, my CSS styling for these two elements do not work because they fall outside the `image-summary` div.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype=
        "http://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <div class="article-image-summary" itemprop="image">
                <meta content="auto">
                <meta content="100"><a href="#"><img alt=
                "#" itemprop="url" src=
                "#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article-tag-summary" itemprop="articleSection">
            <a href="#>tag</a>
        </div><!--<div class="article-data">-->
        <div class="article-date-summary" itemprop="datePublished">
            date
            <div class="page-views">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> count
            </div>
        </div><!--</div>-->
        <h2 class="title-article-masonry" itemprop="headline"></h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think your snippet displays your issue correctly. The image is missing.

Comment: If the CSS isn't working can you post the CSS?

Comment: @Zack, I rephrased my question, it is not a CSS problem.

Comment: @sdexp - I rephrased my question, it is not a CSS problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. If you want certain divs to fall under another div, put them there...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - ofcourse I can do that, but that implications, I described them clearly. I do 1 thing, I get 1 bad consequence, I do another, then I get another bad consequence. I try to solve it with no bad consequences for my code structure.

Comment: You should close the DIV so it's option 1. If you want help with the CSS you should probably post it.

Comment: @raulbaros The issue you describe in #1, "this is bad for my CSS styling", could possibly be solved, but you've said that this is not a CSS problem. The HTML issue you've presented is impossible to solve with the requirements you've presented (having a div under another one but not under it).

Comment: @raulbaros Why are you not using the HTML5 `article` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to solve this with Microdata’s `itemref` attribute.

For that to work, you have to move the `article-tag-summary` and the `article-date-summary` (and perhaps other properties that follow) outside of the `schema:Article` element.

Give each property an `id`, and reference these `id` values in the `itemref` attribute ("foo1" and "foo2" in my example):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="foo1 foo2">

  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="foo1" class="article-tag-summary" itemprop="articleSection">
</div>

<div id="foo2" class="article-date-summary" itemprop="datePublished">
</div>
```

If you need a grouping `div` for all of these parts, you can of course add it. As you use Schema.org’s `Article` type, the `article` element is most likely more appropriate than a `div`.